# Javascript in browser, how to call function when 1 script file fully loaded, but do not care about other resources

Tags: javascript, dom, loading

In my html I have 2 script tags:

```
<script src="first.js"></script> 
<script src="second.js"></script>
```

first.js is a large library file, and would make `funcFromFirstJs` available. I want to call this func when it becomes ready. Sometimes, first.js doesn't have enough time to finish loading before second.js is executed. I currently use this recursive strategy like so:

// second.js

```
function callIfReady() {
  if (typeof funcFromFirstJs === 'function') {
    funcFromFirstJs();
  } else {
    // wait for a few seconds and callIfReady() again
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?
I am aware of `window event 'load' which is supposed to fire when all sources in html including images have finished loading completely`. I'm also aware of `document event DOMContentLoaded which happens when tags are loaded, but may happen before their content completely finishes loading`.
Because `first.js` is a library file, so I also do not want to add my js code at the bottom of `first.js`.
So specifically, I just want to wait for first.js to finish loading completely, then run this code in `second.js`. I certainly do `not` care about the loading progress of other things like images or other script tags; this is why I do `not` want to use `window event: load`.

Comment: Does calling `funcFromFirstJs();` in a `<script>` element immediately following the `<script>` element which defines it not work?  It's not clear to me what the actual problem is.

Comment: note that you don't need to do this in modern JS. You just write `<script src="script1.js" type="module" async></script>` and you your _script file_ you say `import { whatever, you, need } from "script2.js"` using [Javascript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). Your HTML doesn't need to know which scripts depend on which other scripts, you manage that on the JS side.

Comment: @David , oh, my problem is that the first script sometimes doesn't have enough time to finish loading fully before script2 is executed.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Cool idea. I know HTML itself should not bother with js inter-dependencies. With this approach, no need for any bundler setup, right? I'm using the library is chart.js (the first.js in my dummy example), which exposes the global function `Chart`. So would I simply `import * as Chart from "chart.js"`?

Comment: Indeed, normal JS modules do not need a bundler. As for chart.js, just import the module version, there's like 10 different flavours of that library you can use. Give the chartjs website a browse, it's definitely covered.

Comment: "*first.js doesn't have enough time to finish loading before second.js is executed*" - I can't see how that is happening. Without `async` or `defer`, the scripts run sequentially, one after the other, in the order in which they appear in the document.

Comment: @Bergi you might be right. I probably made a wrong observation initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you were my colleague, I'd firstly ask you why you decided to use such approach at all and why you don't use any bundler which could effectively merge all your scripts into a single file, as well as minimise its size via tree-shaking.

However, if you still want to achieve the behaviour described in your question, one of the approaches you may use is: to add the first script from the second one and wait until 'onload' event fires. Like this:

```
// second.js

function callWhenReady() {
    funcFromFirstJs(); //everything you need from the first.js
}

const s = document.createElement('script'); // create script element
document.body.appendChild(s); // append it to the DOM
s.onload = callWhenReady; // execute when script loaded
s.src = 'https://...path/to/first.js'; // set path to script
```

With this slightly tricky solution you should be able to execute anything you need from the `first.js` script in the function `callWhenReady';

P.S.
Of course you should remove ` from the HTML in this case.

Comment: Reason I'm trying to be as vanilla as I can: The library js file is already minimized, and preferably I don't want to use webpack to process it again. Also, among my 10 pages, only 2 pages need the library js file, I don't want / need to load this library on the 8 other HTML pages. Your suggestion is quite nice. Do you think of the other comment -> the one regarding "<script src="script1.js" type="module" async></script>" then in script 2,  `import {x} from "script1.js" `

Comment: @Morris yes, I think it should work in modern browsers, actually all of them.
 My solution is kind of "classic" and may work in older browsers as well, if necessary.